# Use external .config file without path

Tags: c#, configuration, path

I made application and it works. But now I have problem on making Setup .exe file. 
I want my .config file be local network ( If need I can manual move him there ). That .config file need to use all PCs in same local network, for easy updating and fast updating. Problem is there I don't see a way to do that. I can't place path to my code because I have more local networks and some day they can change addresses, so I can't hard code. Every solution is welcome ( make .exe file on network and all to have shortcut on PCs is also good idea )

Comment: Can you place a path in the .config file itself?
I.e.: `<appSettings file="global.app.config">`

Comment: @Marcel it's not possible I think

Comment: Wirting absolute or relative paths there works. BTDT. So you can include a common config file there. But it might not fit your needs because it is still an absolute path, and you have to deploy different config files in different subnets. But it is at least easier to maintain than hard coded paths, which are evil.